# Spacial clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

Given a collection of points on a 2D plane, I want to find collections of `X` points that are within `Y` of each other.  For example:

```
8|
7|    a     b
6|
5|       c
4|
3|                    e
2|                  d          
1|
-------------------------
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are points on the 2D plane.  Given arguments of 3 for the number of points (`X`) and 3 for the distance (`Y`), the algorithm would return `[[a, b, c]]`.  Some examples:

```
algorithm(X = 3, Y = 3) returns [[a, b, c]]
algorithm(X = 2, Y = 3) returns [[a, b, c], [d, e]] -- [a, b, c] contains at least two points
algorithm(X = 4, Y = 3) returns [] -- no group of 4 points close enough
algorithm(X = 5, Y = 15) returns [[a, b, c, d, e]]
```

Constraints:

- x and y axis (the numbers above) are both 10,000 units long
- there are 800 points (a, b, c, d etc) on the graph
- I don't think it matters, but I'm using JavaScript

---

Things I've tried:

- I actually care about outputting new points that are close to more than one input point, so I tried iterating on a grid and 'looking around' it using Pythagoras to find each point a given distance away.  This is too slow given the total area.  [See the source here](https://github.com/sennett/schools/blob/master/clusterFinder.js#L45). 
  You can also see the data size in [real data test](https://github.com/sennett/schools/blob/master/clusterFinder.test.js#L140).
- [DBSCAN](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68), which seems to have a different purpose - I know how big I want my cluster size to be.
- I'm [currently](https://github.com/sennett/schools/blob/master/clusterFinder.js#L1) trying to compare points to each other and build up close pairs, then close triplets, etc, until the end, but this seems to be going down a bit of an inefficiency hole also.  I'm going to continue and try some kind of hashing or dictionary to avoid these loops.

Comment: BTW this isn't homework - I'm moving country with two kids and getting them into school is nightmare, with waiting lists based on straight-line distance.

Comment: You could turn it into a graph problem. Create a complete graph where the weights of the edges are the distance. Now for every node check all `n - 1` neighbours edge weights and see if `X` of them have a weight less than or equal to `Y`. It would be `O(N^2)` to build it the first time but after that all queries will only be `O(N)`

Comment: @MitchelPaulin thanks.  It feels like this is where I'm heading with my second attempt but I'm not sure.  Can you point me to a tutorial or some search terms?  I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: I guess you would want to start with looking at the graph data structure https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/graph_data_structure.htm

Comment: "algorithm(X = 2, Y = 3) returns [[a, b, c], [d, e]]" That first collection has three points though, not 2.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez yes it does.  Should contain at least 2 points.  Updating question.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize if there are multiple possible answers?

Comment: @juvian I'm trying to find clusters of points less than X distance apart, and numbering at least Y.  Check out the answer from David below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only 800 points, you can probably just build the graph by comparing each pair, then run [Bron--Kerbosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) to find maximal cliques. Here's a legit-seeming Javascript implementation of that algorithm: https://github.com/SeregPie/almete.BronKerbosch

Comment: This is promising thanks.  I'll mark as accepted when I see it perform with my constraints.

Comment: @sennett If it's not fast enough you can try transforming the graph into its k=X-1 core (iteratively delete vertices of degree less than X-1; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory))

Comment: More than quick enough.  Thanks.